# Mean of several .mat files of a 3-D Matrix

Tags: matlab, mean, latitude-longitude, dimensions, mat-file

I have several .mat files, which are all in a 3-D matrix of latitude x longitude x value (70 x 70 x 8760).

It looks like this:
year2000.mat --> (72 x 70 x 8760),
year2001.mat --> (72 x 70 x 8760),until year 2020

I need the long-term mean along the third dimensions-the value. The result should be again a .mat file with 3-Dimension (72 x 70 x 8760). The first and second dimensions don't change.

I am very new to Matlab.

Comment: what have you tried? where did you get stuck ?

Comment: files = dir('*.mat');
for file = files'
    mat = load(file.name);
    variable =mat.variable;
    m = mean(variable ,3)
end ... but this is not doing the long-term mean

Comment: great! I'd edit this info into the question I

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you did well in loading the files but since you know all the files start with `year` you can do:

```
fn = dir('year*.mat');
```

Then, you load the files, but if I understand you correctly you want to mean the years, not each year. so,

```
data = zeros(72,70,8760);
for n=1:numel(fn)
      single_year = load(fn(n).name);
      data = data + single_year.variable ; 
 end
```

is  variable  really the name if the  variable  in each mat file? I just used what you wrote, but you should check what you get if  you load a single file.

now the avg is just the sum over the `n`:

```
 data=data./numel(fn);
```